# Enhanced WooCommerce Custom Fields for Variations

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Using the [Remi Coulson](https://remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/) tutorial, a custom field has been added for product variations.

This works, however the custom field is positioned by the add-to-cart button. I wish to position it within Additional Information tab. I have tried adding the front end code to the additional-information.php but it does not display.

```
 <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
    {{{ data.variation.text_field }}}
</div>
```

Added to functions.php to display variation

```
   // Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Create new fields for variations
 *
*/
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
        )
    );

}

/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
*/
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {

    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
    

}

<?php

// Add New Variation Settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );

/**
 * Add custom fields for variations
 *
*/
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {
    
    // duplicate the line for each field
    $variations['text_field'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_text_field', true );
    
    return $variations;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3.

jQuery and some other changes are required to display the selected variation custom field value anywhere in a specific location on single product pages, specially outside the variation form.

In the example below the **selected** variation custom field value will be displayed on "Additional information" product tab after product attributes table.

Here is the complete revisited code:

```
// Add a custom field to variation settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_text_field[' . $loop . ']',
        'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'http://',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true ),
    ) );
}

// Save custom field value from variation settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_variation_object', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
function save_variation_settings_fields( $variation, $loop ) {
    if( isset($_POST['_text_field'][$loop]) ) {
        $variation->update_meta_data( '_text_field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_text_field'][$loop]) );
    }
}

// Add variation custom field to single variable product form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_variation_custom_field_to_variable_form', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_custom_field_to_variable_form( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['text_field'] = $variation->get_meta('_text_field');

    return $variation_data;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'add_html_container_to_display_selected_variation_custom_field' );
function add_html_container_to_display_selected_variation_custom_field( $product ){
    echo '<div class="custom_variation-text-field"></div>';
}

// Display selected variation custom field value to product the tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'display_selected_variation_custom_field_js' );
function display_selected_variation_custom_field_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            $('.custom_variation-text-field').text(data.text_field);
        }).on('hide_variation', function(event) {
            $('.custom_variation-text-field').text('');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.